# Java Random Choice

Tags: java

So i have been working on my first Java game and it is going great, but i need to pick a random one of the int's, and out them in here;
Example (INCORRECT, Just how i imagine it)

```
private static void encouter() {
   random(EnmyClass + (Goblin + Mage))
```

... So on

So thats how i see it please note all of that is probably wrong.
Heres the actual code;

```
    package com.company;
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    static Scanner rand = new Random();
    static dice die = new dice();
    public static String playerName;
    public static int Hp;
    public static int MaxHp;
    public static int EnmyHp;
    public static int Damage;
    public static int EnmyDamage;
    public static int EnmyClass;
    public static int Mana;
    public static int Level;
    private static void Stats() {
        if (EnmyClass.equals("Goblin")) {
            System.out.println(playerName + EnmyHp + Hp + Damage + EnmyDamage + Mana);
        } else {
            System.out.println(playerName + EnmyHp + Hp + Damage + EnmyDamage);
        }
    }
    private static void buildGoblin() {
        EnmyClass = "Goblin";
        EnmyHp = 10;
        EnmyDamage = 7;
        Level = 1;
        }
    private static void buildEnemy() {
        switch (Level) {
            case 1:
                MaxHp = 10;
                break;
            case 2:
                MaxHp = 20;
                break;
            case 3:
                MaxHp = 30;
                break;
    private static void encounter() 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @Jason how can i make it pick a random one of the Enemys (i Know there is only one rn)

Answer (score 1):

1. Variables in java start with a lower case, classes with an upper case. Learn this now or you (and others) will be confused
2. You can add them to an array and select one from a random index.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Test {
    static int[] stats = new int[3];

    static int health = 100;
    static int stamina = 200;
    static int size = 10;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random rand = new Random();

        stats[0] = health;
        stats[1] = stamina;
        stats[2] = size;

        // If you want a random int from 0-9
        int n = rand.nextInt(10);

        // If you want to select a random stat
        int stat = stats[rand.nextInt(stats.length)];

        System.out.println(stat);
    }
}
```

3. What you *probably* want to do is make a POJO for an enemy or character, that has all of these stats.

```
class Enemy {
  String type;
  int health;
  int stamina;

  public Enemy(String t, int h, int s) {
    this.type = t;
    this.health = h;
    this.stamina = s;
  }

  // Getters and setters
}
```

Comment: Thank you sleepToken